# Visual studio project template replaces "$(SolutionDir)" macro in template on build

Tags: visual-studio, templates, msbuild, csproj, visual-studio-templates

I am trying to make a project template for internal use that has all of the custom parts of our assembly versioning system.

The default project template works perfectly with our pre-build and post-build event but when I try to reference a file using the `$(SolutionDir)` macro it gets replaced during the building of the template and

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Compile Include="$(SolutionDir)\CommonAssemblyInfo.cs">
      <Link>Properties\CommonAssemblyInfo.cs</Link>
   </Compile>
   <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Gets turned into the following when the project template is used to generate a project in solution:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Compile Include="..\..\..\..\..\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\n0u03z2x.gpe\CommonAssemblyInfo.cs">
     <Link>Properties\CommonAssemblyInfo.cs</Link>
   </Compile>
   <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The template `build/package` process is probably replacing this.

*How do I escape it ?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Visual studio project template replaces “$(SolutionDir)” macro in template on build

You should set [CreateInPlace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247196(v=vs.110).aspx) in the `.vstemplate` file of the exported project template to **true**, like `<CreateInPlace>true</CreateInPlace>`.

Following is my `.vstemplate` file:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Project">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>TestDemo</Name>
    <Description>&lt;No description available&gt;</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <ProjectSubType>
    </ProjectSubType>
    <SortOrder>1000</SortOrder>
    <CreateNewFolder>true</CreateNewFolder>
    <DefaultName>TestDemo</DefaultName>
    <ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>
    <LocationField>Enabled</LocationField>
    <EnableLocationBrowseButton>true</EnableLocationBrowseButton>
    <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
    <CreateInPlace>true</CreateInPlace>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <Project TargetFileName="TestDemo.csproj" File="TestDemo.csproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="Class1.cs">Class1.cs</ProjectItem>
      <Folder Name="Properties" TargetFolderName="Properties">
        <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="AssemblyInfo.cs">AssemblyInfo.cs</ProjectItem>
      </Folder>
    </Project>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

Detailed steps:

1. Export the project template without **Automatically import the template into Visual Studio**:
   [image]
2. Unzip the exported file, add `<CreateInPlace>true</CreateInPlace>` into the `MyTemplate.vstemplate` file, and zip all the files.
3. Copy this file to the folder: `C:\Users\<Username>\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ProjectTemplates`
4. Restart your Visual Studio, create a new project with the new custom template.

   [image]

With this setting, this issue should be fix. But the weird thing is that the documentation states that the default value for `CreateInPlace` is true.

[image]

Hope this helps.