# Visual studio 2017 Community project template

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-templates

I have tried to create a custom project template for Visual Studio Community 2017 for c++. I have exported the project as a template, however when I try to access the files I added in a new project, they are not created in the project folder. I can try to open them in the Solution Explorer, but the files themselves are not being created. I have tried to add `<CreateinPlace>true</CreateInPlace>` as well as adding the .zip files to the VS template directory, but these had no effect. How would I be able to add the files to the template and get them to show up in a new project?

Comment: I'm having the same issue as well. None of the "fixes" seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it actually was is that the `.vstemplate` wasn't adding the files as project items, so when I exported the project, it didn't know to look for them.
To fix it I just added

```
<TemplateContent>
        <Project TargetFileName="CS235-Template.vcxproj" File="CS235-Template.vcxproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
            <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName="$projectname$.vcxproj.filters">CS235-Template.vcxproj.filters</ProjectItem>
            <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="main.cpp">main.cpp</ProjectItem>
            <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="Debug.h">Debug.h</ProjectItem>
            <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="input.txt">input.txt</ProjectItem>
        </Project>
    </TemplateContent>
```

After doing this they worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio stores the template in 3 different locations. The folder that VS tells you is only one of the 3 options. I finally modified the .`vstemplate` file in:

```
Libraries\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ProjectTemplates
```

- Unzip the file (`Right-Click->Extract All`)
- Open the `.vstemplate` file
- Add `<CreateInPlace>true</CreateInPlace>` to the `<TemplateData>` section
- Save the file
- Rezip the file (or don't. It works either way but if you leave the zip file the template will show up twice)

The following answer is a little off topic but it's the one that helped me solve the problem.
[Answer][https://stackoverflow.com/a/48274550/4892466]